# Read data file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, text-files

I am trying to read a text file and store it in an array, but my program keeps getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Here is my code:

```
int main () {
    const int size = 10000; //s = array size
    int ID[size];
    int count = 0; //loop counter
    ifstream employees;

    employees.open("Employees.txt");
    while(count < size && employees >> ID[count]) {
        count++;
    }

    employees.close(); //close the file 

    for(count = 0; count < size; count++) { // to display the array 
        cout << ID[count] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run it in debugger?

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code? I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: Infinite loop ? Your code will produce at most 10000 iterations for each loop...

Comment: @LinaHossamEl-deen: try to put one `breakpoint` at `employe.close()` and one at `cout << endl`. then see where it is going for an infinite loop. Probably it will give your answer

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use a `std::vector<int> ID;` instead of a raw `int` array.

Secondly, your loop should look more like this:

```
std:string line;
while(std::getline(employees, line)) //read a line from the file
{
    ID.push_back(atoi(line.c_str()));  //add line read to vector by converting to int
}
```

EDIT:

Your problem in the above code is this:

```
for(count = 0; count < size; count++) {
```

You're reusing your count variable that you used earlier to keep count of the number of items you read from your file.

It should be something like this:

```
for (int x = 0;  x < count; x++) {
   std::cout << ID[x] << " ";
}
```

Here you're using your `count` variable to print the number of items read from the file.

Comment: 1. You don't know that all the employee IDs are on separate lines; the original code will work if they are space separated. (You could give `std::getline` a different delimiter I suppose). 2. This doesn't answer the question (although admittedly good practices can help avoid stupid bugs). And while I agree `std::vector` is usually a good idea even if the size is always fixed, in this case it would be a good idea to call [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid a lot of reallocations.